# Layover at Zurich

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, us-citizens, zrh

I'm flying from Israel on El Al with a 2 hour stopover in Zurich (on a US passport) before I board an American Airlines flight to the US. Is 2 hours sufficient and do I have to clear immigration and customs in Zurich?

Comment: Is it one ticket?

Comment: One ticket: yes. Two tickets: no.

Answer (score 2):

As this is a international, outside Schengen connection you will not have to deal with customs or immigration. You will only have to pass through security, and for that those 2 hours are more than sufficient.

Comment: Provided the two flights are on the same ticket of course. Otherwise it’s a no-no.